# Missing diacritics in GT table output

Tags: r, formatting, diacritics, gt

I am using GT package in R to create tables for my diploma thesis and I ran into a problem. The diploma is to be written in the czech language.

When GT draws the table it does not display the letter ě properly and shows e instead.

The code for GT table:

```
desc_sex[,2:ncol(desc_sex)] %>% gt(rowname_col = "sex"
  ) %>% tab_stubhead(
    label = html("Kategorie")
  ) %>% cols_align(
    align = "center",
    columns = everything()
  ) %>% cols_label(
    n = html("n"),
    procent = html("%")
  ) %>% tab_row_group(
    label = html("<b>Sledované regiony celkem"),
    rows = 7:9
  ) %>% tab_row_group(
    label = html("<b>Krajský soud v Ostravě"),
    rows = 4:6
  ) %>% tab_row_group(
    label = html("<b>Městský soud v Praze"),
    rows = 1:3
  ) %>% summary_rows(
    groups = T,
    fns = list(
      Celkem = ~sum(.)),
    formatter = fmt_number,
    decimals = 0
  )
```

Here are the data in CSV compliant format:

```
"reg_reside","sex","n","procent","single"
"MSPH","Muž",93,46.5,52
"MSPH","Žena",83,41.5,34
"MSPH","Manželský pár",24,12,0
"KSOS","Muž",113,56.5,51
"KSOS","Žena",68,34,30
"KSOS","Manželský pár",19,9.5,0
"Celkem","Muž",206,51.5,103
"Celkem","Žena",151,37.8,64
"Celkem","Manželský pár",43,10.8,0
```

Here is how the output looks in GT - the mistake is in Ostrave (should be Ostravě) and Mestsky (should be Městský):

[image: Output from GT]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using html entities like i.e. ě = `&ecaron;`

```r
desc_sex[,2:ncol(desc_sex)] %>%
    gt(rowname_col = "sex") %>%
    tab_stubhead(label = html("Kategorie")) %>%
    cols_align(align = "center",columns = everything()) %>%
    cols_label(n = html("n"),
               procent = html("%")) %>%
    tab_row_group(label = html("<b>Sledované regiony celkem"),
                  rows = 7:9) %>%
    tab_row_group(label = html("<b>Krajský soud v Ostrav&ecaron;"),
                  rows = 4:6) %>%
    tab_row_group(label = html("<b>M&ecaron;stský soud v Praze"),
                  rows = 1:3) %>%
    summary_rows(groups = T,
                 fns = list(Celkem = ~sum(.)),
                 formatter = fmt_number,
                 decimals = 0)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was dreading the possibility of having to redo all tables in excel.